BadRequestError: 400 Invalid content type. image_url is only supported by certain models
I am trying to use Open ai's gpt-4-turbo model for image-to-text description generation
but I am facing this issue- BadRequestError: 400 Invalid content type. image_url is only supported by certain models.
app.post('/analyze-image', cors(corsOptions), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { image } = req.body;
    const base64Image = await convertBufferToBase64(image);
    // Pass base64Image to OpenAI API
    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-4-turbo",
      messages: [
        {
          role: "user",
          content: [
            { type: "text", text: "What's in this image?" },
            { type: "image_url", url: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Image}` },

          ],
        },
      ],
    });
    res.json(response.choices[0]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Error analyzing image');
  }
});

Even I tried with a url ,but same error was getting for the Url
how to fix this ?

Use gpt-4o or gpt-4o-mini model for image input (vision support).

it not works with  4o-mini either...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78848020/invalid-content-type-image-url-is-only-supported-by-certain-models

I sometimes see the same error with even gpt-4o - "Invalid content type. image_url is only supported by certain models."

GPT official documentation says it support image url as input. I used image url first and got an error that "expected object but got a string". Then I wrapped up image url as "url":"xxx' and then got this error. I use gpt4-o
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': 'Invalid image.', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': 'invalid_image'}}

https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create
