Invalid content type. image_url is only supported by certain models
That's my Python request:
def analyze_screenshot_base64(encoded_image):
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {openai.api_key}"
    }

    payload = {
        "model": "gpt-4o-mini",
        "messages": [
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": "Develop a trading setup (LONG or SHORT) with a CRV of at least 5 based on this chart. Include entry price, stop loss, and take profit levels."
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "image_url",
                        "image": {
                            "url": f"data:image/png;base64,{encoded_image}"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "max_tokens": 300
    }

    response = requests.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", headers=headers, json=payload)
    return response.json()

But the API returns me:

{'error': {'message': 'Invalid content type. image_url is only
supported by certain models.', 'type': 'invalid_request_error',
'param': 'messages.[0].content.[1].type', 'code': None}}

What could be the problem?

Maybe you should not use image_url as content type? Or you should make sure that a model is used that supports it?

Although the error message seems to suggest that you might be using the wrong model, this is not the case.
When specifying the image content:
{
    "type": "image_url",
    "image": {
        "url": f"data:image/png;base64,{encoded_image}"
    }
}

you need to use image_url rather than image.
So this becomes:
{
    "type": "image_url",
    "image_url": {
        "url": f"data:image/png;base64,{encoded_image}"
    }
}

I have checked this by running part your code, and I get the same error. If I change it to image_url it works perfectly.

i got the same error.
I want to upload images, save them in a folder and then pass them to gpt4-o
   for image_url in image_urls:
        messages[0]["content"].append({
            "type": "image_url",
            "image_url": {
                "url": image_url
            }
        })

I used this function to serve the image and verified the url works.
What to change..?
def serve_image(filename):
    return send_from_directory(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)

